# How do you need to change the human brain to learn as easily as children in adulthood?

Tags: creature-design, hard-science

As many people know, young children (up to three to five years old) are much better able to learn than people in adulthood or already old age.  This is mainly due to the fact that at birth the brain areas resemble rough sketches without details and undifferentiated.  Then comes the sensitive period of childhood - the magical era of neuroplasticity, the rough sketch becomes detailed.

During the sensitive period, the cerebral cortex is so plastic that it can easily change under the influence of a new stimulus.  This sensitivity allows children to easily learn new skills and languages, just by listening and observing others.  After the end of the sensitive period, you will have to make an effort to concentrate and memorize for learning.

During the sensitive period, the "learning mechanism" is constantly on, because  the brain does not know what it will be important for it, it assimilates everything.  Only the brain, which is already characterized by a certain degree of organization, can draw voluntary attention.

Brain neurotrophic factor (BDNF) plays a decisive role in the sensitive period, it strengthens the connections between neurons that actively work together during this period.  BDNF also activates the nucleus basalis, the part of the brain that helps focus attention.  When the sensitive period ends, BDNF turns off the basal nucleus, and now it can already be activated only when something very important, unusual appears, or when a person makes serious efforts to concentrate.

And here we come to the essence of my question: how do I need to change the human brain of my genetically modified person in order to enable him to learn just as easily in adulthood, but at the same time without losing its other properties (memory, etc.)?

Comment: They have made animals more like people, but they haven't made people more like (something more human than human). You may be able to engineer brilliance, but that's different. Guessing you're looking for prolonged immaturity, but you can't have both stable and unstable memory. Maybe genetic eidetic memory, but that's different too. This approach may lead to learning drugs, but that's experimental and hypothetical.  I think you'd have people with lifelong vulnerability to trauma who would need to be sheltered from the world, but there's no hard science for this because it doesn't exist.

Comment: "*Young children (up to three to five years old) are much better able to learn than people in adulthood or already old age":* citation very strongly needed. They are better at *learning languages*, but that's only a small subset of learning. As far as I know, children at such an early age are very poor at reasoning, which is an essential component of learning calculus, for example. Fundamentally, I absolutely don't believe you that children under five are that much better at learning anything other than languages. AFAIK, young adults (up to, 14 to 30) are best at learning serious stuff.

Comment: What sort of learning? Memorization,? Acquiring language? Motor skills? These all use different parts of the brain.  Also a lot of early childhood learning is done by *losing* superfluous connections rather than building new ones. I can think of answers but of course hard science is difficult because AFAIK no one has attempted anything like this. Can you define more clearly the age range of the children and what you allow to be done? Can we propose a (much) larger skull?

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer but I agree that a citation is needed. From my own personal experience, I am much more efficient at learning now in my mid-20s than I have ever been. I would suspect that the slower-rate of learning is not so much physical but cultural. In the UK, the education system trains memorisation but not learning (short term vs long term). You can learn languages very quickly as an adult if you understand how learning works. I am strongly inclined to believe that the main hurdle here is simply self-belief and enthusiasm and not hard-wired biology.

Comment: Downvoted because it is based on a false assumption.  Children are not better able to learn, in general.  The exception is languages (and perhaps language-like things, such as music), which are learned at an instinctive level.  It usually requires a couple of decades of growth before an individual can really deal with anything that requires logical thought or a long attention span.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad idea. You see there is a phenomenon called [childhood amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood_amnesia). There are speculations on reasons, but most agree that it is closly connected to that "fast childhood learning". So your modified adults may acquire some skills fast but for the price of having some mess instead of memories of their lives.

I personally prefere theory that it is due to massive new neurons growth. Child's brain need to "assimilate" quite a lot of new population. Thus it desperately needs to be very flexible in changing it's structure and have ability to teach "newborns" fast. Or it would just stop functioning.

To achive this in adult's brain we need to kill some old neurons first. Adults skull is not that flexible (and shouldn't be) and have a constant volume. So to add some biomass in the skull we, need to remove some biomass from there at first.

Removing old neurons means forgeting old skills and (again) loosing memories.

So if for your setting total amnesia is ok (or even may be preferable - for, say, genetecly modifed assassins) you may:

1. Induce apoptosis of specially geneticaly-marked neurons (to not paralise person or make him forget how to breath) by some hormonal stimulus (either external, or have some special gland modifications). And also make shure that connective tissue is not taking place of dying neurons.
2. Introduсe enough special "neuron stem cells" into brain (always have some their or just inject it)
3. Induce brain regrowth by some hormonal stimulus (same as at phase 1 or other)

On phase 1) human would become mentally impared, on phase 3) he can begin his reeducation.

If you don't need that fast learning rate - this process can go at slower rate, but constantly (all 3 phases simultaneously at parallel). Then you would get humans with memory and complex skill span of about 3-5-10-20 years (depending on the rate) but who can (and need to) learn times faster than non-modified human. If you master violin (3 old can do this), you forget all your masteries of piano with memories of perfoming it. Quite a happy nation!